# Can you make games, animations, etc in ApplescriptObjC?

Tags: objective-c, applescript-objc

I tackled ApplescriptObjC. I started making apps with the interface builder and such. But can you make actual games in ApplescriptObjC like you can in normal Objective-C? What is the difference other than the syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference. AppleScript-ObjC is a way of speaking to Cocoa using AppleScript instead of Objective-C. Whatever you can do with Cocoa in one language you can do in another language: Objective-C, AppleScript, Swift, whatever.

Some APIs are C APIs, and some calls may work best using C or Objective-C. But *in general* the matter of language is irrelevant; that is what a "bridge" *means*.